# Add a Javascript array to POST variable on form submit

Tags: jquery, post

I have a Javascript array that I would like to add to the post array when a form is submitted.  The Javascript array should be added in addition to other variables already being posted from the form.  Is there a way to do this in JQuery?

Ex.

Form:

```
<form id="my-form" action="/create.php" method="post">
<input id="first_name" type="text" /> 
<input id="last_name" type="text" /> 
</form>
```

Javascript array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var external_ids = [{"name":"SSN","value":"555-55-5555"},    
{"name":"PID","value":"GBNT22"}];

</script>
```

This is what I would like the resulting PHP $_POST array to look like, if possible:

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Smith
    [external_ids]=>
        (
            [SSN] => 555-55-5555
            [PID] => GBNT22
        )
)
```

Comment: see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322632/is-it-possible-to-submit-javascript-array-along-with-form-submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
var external_ids = [{"name": "SSN", "value": "555-55-5555"},
                    {"name": "PID", "value": "GBNT22"}];

// form fields
var values = {};
var fields = $('#myForm :input');
$.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    var dom = $(field),
        name = dom.attr('id'),
        value = dom.val();
    values[name] = value;
});

// add array
values.external_ids = {};
$.each(external_ids, function(i, field) {
    values.external_ids[field.name] = field.value;
});

// post data
$.post('/endpoint', values);​
```

Find the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbE6g/1/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is the serialize() function on jQuery. Had you check this?

Or you can use something like this:

```
function onSubmit(){
    var toSend = [
        first_name : 'John',
        last_name : 'Smith',
        external_ids : {
            SSN: '555-55-5555',
            PID: 'GBNT22'
        }
    ];

    $.post( yourUrl, toSend, function(data){
        //callback
    } );
```

}

Comment: How would this look in a JQuery event handler?