# (JS_console) Why does this loop break when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute this code in the console, what I want to do is change the value of a few fields and keep submitting.

```
var animal = new Array(); //Declare Array 

animal[0] = 'cat';
animal[1] = 'dog';
animal[2] = 'cow';
animal[3] = 'snake';
animal[4] = 'goat';
animal[5] = 'tiger';
animal[6] = 'lion';
animal[7] = 'horse';


var createFunc = function(i){
    return function(){
        var token_field = document.getElementById('animal_name'); 
        token_field.value = animal[i]; //Change the value of the field with each array value

        var path_field = document.getElementById('To_do');
        path_field.value='feed'; // Change the other field with 'feed'

        var submit_all = document.getElementById('graph_submit');
        submit_all.click(); //submit the form
    };
};
for (var i = 0; token.length > i; i++) {
    setTimeout(createFunc(i), 2000);
}
```

But when the button is being clicked, the page is reloaded and loop broken... So, only the 1st value gets submitted and others remain.

After 1st submit (which will be made in above 2 seconds) execution of code of submitted page is stopped. Page will be reloaded due to POST query. But I want all the values to be submitted, but the page is reloaded.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Put some console.log in createFunc and check. Whether it is getting called after each 2 sec.

Comment: Not related: Don't use primitive constructors. They are [so much slower](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-literal/15) and return incorrect values.

Comment: @Manish, Yes it is being called.... But As Maxim said, it gets reloaded for which loop breaks. but I want to end the loop and get my job done, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that on click of 'graph_submit' scope gets changed and the loop breaks.

You can use prevent default function here.

Comment: No It does not get changed. It remains same. Actually, After 1st submit (which will be made in above 2 seconds) execution of code of submitted page is stopped. Page will be reloaded due to POST query. But I want all the values to be submitted, but the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly your code. But for 1st look I can guess that you create queue of submits of page.

After 1st submit (which will be made in above 2 seconds) execution of code of submitted page is stopped. Page will be reloaded due to POST query.

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var animals = new Array();
        animals[0] = 'cat';
        animals[1] = 'dog';
        animals[2] = 'cow';
        animals[3] = 'snake';
        animals[4] = 'goat';
        animals[5] = 'tiger';
        animals[6] = 'lion';
        animals[7] = 'horse';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#q').attr('value', JSON.stringify(animals));

            $('#ajax').click(function () {
                $.post("/", JSON.stringify(animals));
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form id="main" action="http://www.google.com/search">
        <input id="q" name="q" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Using submit" />
        <input id="ajax" type="button" value="Using ajax" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

"Using ajax" post data you can check in firebug. It will be the same.

["cat","dog","cow","snake","goat","tiger","lion","horse"]

I think you need to read about some basics of HTML forms, ajax requests and HTTP methods.

Comment: Yes, That is exactly what is happening... I guess It does reload. Is there anything I can do about it? I need all the array values posted one by one but If this keeps happening, only 1st value is posted, and other remain. What can I do about it?

Comment: I guess you do not need any delays between requests. Simply pass all items to server in single POST. You can use jQuery to make it easy: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227413/add-a-javascript-array-to-post-variable-on-form-submit)

Comment: Thanks... No I do understand the problem but when I use $.POST(); in the console, it gives an error 'TypeError: $.GET is not a function', is there any solution about this one dude?

Comment: I will write answer with sample how to pass array to server using post and jquery. It is obviously easy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. here need some more clarification. Why are you using setTimeout? Because in every loop you are only sending i. One is your loop and other is setTimeOut which is creating conflict.

So Here is some suggestions :

1. Remove setTimeOut and only use for loop. (If you have to only submit the form only 'token.length' time.)
2. If you have to submit the form after every 2 sec then remove the for loop and only use setTimeOut. And for passing 'i' to createFunc you can use one counter. ex :

   ```js
   setTimeout( 
     function(){
       var i =0;
       createFunc(i);
       i++;
   } , 2000);
   ```

Please do not use both. Perhaps this will helpful and clear.